# Is this this tcp handshake valid? Packets sent with libnet

Tags: tcp, handshake

I am currently programming with libnet and pcap and I captured the following TCP handshake, but the server doesn't except the last step of the handshake and responds with a reset.

x.x.x.1 = client (packets sent using libnet)

x.x.x.2 = server (packets sent by kernel)

Is the third step of the handshake valid? The client has the servers seq.number+1 as acknowledgement since that is the next byte that he expects. Is there any reason why a reset is sent by the server based on this tcpdump? If not  I have to look elsewhere.

x.x.x.1.y > x.x.x.2.y **SYN**, seq 100, length 0 win 65535

x.x.x.2.y > x.x.x.1.y **SYN|ACK**, seq 145411296, ack 101, length 0, options [mss 1460], win 14600

x.x.x.1.y > x.x.x.2.y **SYN|ACK**, seq 101, ack 145411297, length 0, win 65535

x.x.x.2.y > x.x.x.1.y **RST**, seq 145411297, length 0, win 0

Also, what is the time before a connections times out?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found it.

The third step of the handshake should be an ACK not a SYN|ACK.